# VAST Tag Parsing - IM trying to retrieve a movie file from a vast tag

Tags: ads, vast, ssp

http://vid.springserve.com/vast/38264?w=[WIDTH]&h=[HEIGHT]&url=[DOMAIN]&cb=[CACHEBUSTER]

this is my example VAST tag... I need to open a movie file from this, I assume it is in the .js at the bottom but I can't quite figure out how to work it. How can I get a .mp4 advertisement from this VAST tag?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to the MediaFile part of the VAST:

```xml
<MediaFile delivery="progressive" width="640" height="480" apiFramework="VPAID" type="application/javascript">
    <![CDATA[ https://cdn.springserve.com/vd/vd-0.2.21.js ]]>
</MediaFile>
```

The VAST you receive contains a VPAID ad. See `apiFramework="VPAID"` and `type="application/javascript"`. Meaning **you can't get the MP4 from that VAST tag**.

What you can get and use is the VPAID-JS. The VPAID will load and play-out any video and/or animation depending on it's implementation and the underlying ad-server configuration.

@see: [IAB](https://www.iab.com/?s=VAST)

Comment: Can you help me use VPAID to extract the mp4

Comment: Oh, and as I said: It must not have an MP4 anyway ;)

Comment: What is in the .js file then ?

Comment: Any JavaScript VPAID implementation, which will eventually request any video from anywhere.

Comment: doesn't "request any video" imply it will return an .mp4

Comment: First things first: Comments are not made for discussions. Then MP4 isn't the only file format possible. As I said there must not be a video! VPAID must not be implemented in JS. There is nothing within VPAID which enables you to extract the video (if there is one), but this was, what you are asking for. Press F12 within your Browser and find the video resource or use any plugin. Btw, everything you wrote implies that you haven't read the specs. Which then implies, that you haven't read about Stackoverflow how-to articles. Please let's stop this here and have a nice day.